# Confusion over terminology of vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

Normally when I describe a vector space, I describe it in the following format.

$<$Set$>$ is a vector-space over $<$Field$>$.

Lately while I was reading, I ran into another way of saying.

$K$-vector space $R$.

How does my description translate into the way that I'm not familiar with.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: A "$K$-vector space" is a vector space over the field $K$.

Comment: @littleO, since you got here first, you have the right to turn that into an answer (probably best to add a source)

Answer (score 4):

A "$K$-vector space" is a vector space over the field $K$.

After a bit of googling I found this term defined in the notes [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~yskim/M255/w080125.pdf) and also in chapter 1 of the notes Basic Linear Algebra: An Exercise Approach by Gabriel Nagy, which can be found online here: https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/lin-alg/notes.pdf

Comment: For more evidence, [the Wikipedia page for vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) currently mentions the equivalence of the two phrasings (for a field $F$) towards the end of the "definition" section.